# Display overflow-y only there is a difference in height in Angular 2 and higher

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Consider the following code segment:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <div id="leftContentDiv" style="height:125px;">
         ...
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div id="rightContentDiv">
            ...
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The div container with id 'leftContentDiv' has a fixed height size; therefore the div container with id 'rightContentDiv' will adjust to the height size of the div container with id 'leftContentDiv' provided the div container with id 'rightContentDiv' does not have content that exceeds the height size of the div container with id 'leftContentDiv', since these div containers are on the same row.

That being said, may one display a overflow-y when the div container with id 'rightContentDiv' begins to exceed the height size of div container with id 'leftContentDiv' instead of adjusting these div containers to the height size of the div container with the greatest height size.

For example:

HTML:

```
//replace <div id="rightContentDiv"> with <div id="rightContentDiv" [ngClass]="displayVerticalScroll">
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-scroll {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

TS:

```
public displayVerticalScroll(): string {
   let leftContentDivHeight = document.getElementById('leftContentDiv').clientHeight;
   let rightContentDivHeight = document.getElementById('rightContentDiv').clientHeight;
   if (leftContentDivHeight < rightContentDivHeight) {
      return 'vertical-scroll'
   }
}
```

Please advice if this is feasible or perhaps I should approach this differently.

Comment: Why not just using `overflow-y: auto;`?

Comment: try `#rightContentDiv { overflow-y: auto }`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare one variable in the component

```
verticalScroll:boolean = false;

public displayVerticalScroll(): string {
   let leftContentDivHeight = document.getElementById('leftContentDiv').clientHeight;
   let rightContentDivHeight = document.getElementById('rightContentDiv').clientHeight;
   if (leftContentDivHeight < rightContentDivHeight) {
      this.verticalScroll = true;
   }
}
```

In your HTML

```
 <div id="rightContentDiv" [ngClass]="{overflowclass:verticalScroll}">
```